# Prove that $\bar{G}$ contains a triangle

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that If $G$ doesn't contain a triangle then $\bar{G}$ contains one

$G$ is a graph of order at least 6, and $d_{G}(v)\geq 3$ where $v$ is a vertex of $G$

Any hints ?

Comment: This is the immediate result of Ramsey's theorem. In fact the degree of any vertex does not matter. If the number of vertices is at least 6, then there must be a triangle or a "mutually-not-connected" triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $G$ is simple, then the set $N(v)$ (neighbours of $v$) is an independent set of $G$ since $G$ has no triangles. Therefore $\bar{G}$  has a triangle. In fact, any three vertices of $N(v)$ will make a triangle in $\bar{G}$ since $|N(v)| \ge 3$.